# How do I get a a Model I made from the ADO.net entity model designed to only return data dependent on a foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating a website using ASP.NET MVC 5 in Visual Studio 2015, and I am new at this. I am using the ADO.net Entity Data Model to create a model based off my database. And then using a controller with views and Entity Framework.

My question is, that given the user is logged in. He is allowed to see data in that list that belongs to his `UserID`, not other people's. How can I limit the scope to only show data that is limited to only be related to his `UserID`?

The controller's code is still mostly under the default auto generated template.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information this is the best I can do for you.

```
YourContext.SomeTable.Where(s => s.OwnerUserId == currentUser.UserId)
```